# Why is specific heat not zero at absolute zero?

Tags: statistical-thermodynamics, thermodynamics, monte-carlo

In [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.28.3160) old paper on Monte Carlo simulations of Lennard-Jones solid, specific heat behaviour (both $c_p$ and $c_v$) have been reported. As you can see from the picture below, both $c_p$ and $c_v$ goes to $3$ at $0K$. *[The units in the plot are dimensionless reduced units defined based on the Lennard-Jones potential parameters]*
[image]

Now, the heat capacity goes to zero, if the temperature approaches $0K$. Why this is not reflected here? Could this be due to the lack of quantum effects in the simulation?

Comment: +1 but do try to remember next time to avoid MathJax in titles: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct that this is due to not including quantum effects. Ref 1 in your figure is the paper cited below. In this paper, they explicitly mention that $C_v$ calculated using the cell-cluster method is in good agreement only for sufficiently high reduced-temperatures. From section IV of this paper:

> ...the calculation is in acceptable agreement with experiment, except for low reduced temperatures, where quantum- mechanical effects become significant.

As further illustration, this paper has a similar plot of the cell-cluster results, but instead of comparing against Monte Carlo, they compare with experimental results for xenon.

[image: Heat capacities: cell-cluster vs experiment]

As you can see, the experimental results approach zero as they should. The cell-cluster results do at least satisfy [Mayer's Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%27s_relation), which says $C_P-C_V=0$ at $T=\pu{0K}$.

1. K. Westera and E. R. Cowley Phys. Rev. B 11, 4008 (1975) DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevB.11.4008

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but do you know why it goes to 3, the specific heat using cell-cluster method? Because I have seen some MD simulation paper on the same topic (c_p/c_v of LJ solid), and specific heat always goes to 3 reduced unit at low (Zero) temperature.

Comment: @Magic_Number I'm not exactly certain. I know 3 (Nk) shows up in a lot of models of heat capacity (the Dulong-Petit Law, Einstein solid), but I haven't seen any model where the zero temperature limit specifically converges to 3.